# Google Classroom API returns Invitations response with empty data object while invitation is created and tested

Tags: angularjs, google-classroom, google-apis-explorer

```
$scope.listInvitations = function(){
    $http({
        url: 'https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/invitations?userId='+$scope.user.email+'&access_token='+$scope.session.access_token,
        method: 'GET'
    }).then(function(response){
        consoleLog(response);
        if(response.status==200){
            $scope.invitations = response.data.invitations;
        }
    }, function(response){
        consoleLog(response);
    }); 
}
```

[Google Classroom Invitations API Link](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/list)

Following image shows the response.

[Response is shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjPHl.png)

I have checked via 'get' method of invitations using the invitation id, which was returned when I created invitation, that the invitation exists. But I am unable to get the invitations list while the status of response is 200. Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: You're response was empty because you did not indicate which property you were asking for. In the same link you've provided, [Invitations.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations/list), there's a Try-It section. There section you can see the 'fields' parameter where you can place some value found in [Invitation resources](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/invitations#Invitation).

Comment: @noogui I think that is not the issue. Because the property is decided based on what kind of request I am sending. if its a GET method its a list, if its a GET method with an "/<INVITATION_ID>" at the end of url it is get property etc. Isn't it that way?